# flask: Вывод сообщения в зависимости от выполнения условия

Tags: javascript, python, flask

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def signup():
    error = 'Ошибка регистрации'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.form.get('login')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user_add = Users(login = login, password = password, role = 1)
        try:
            db.session.add(user_add)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            pass
        
    return render_template('signup.html')
```

Как в шаблон 'signup.html' вывести сообщение об ошибке регистрации нового пользователя? return 'Ошибка регистрации' сделает это в новом шаблоне, а мне нужен вывод как alert из JS-a

Comment: В [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1530118) я уже писал — вы можете передать переменную в шаблон и на основании её значения отрисовать что-нибудь внутри шаблона https://docs-python.ru/packages/veb-frejmvork-flask-python/funktsija-render-template/

Comment: @andreymal Я сделал все как и было сказано. В except добавил return render_template('signup.html', variable = variable). После чего в самом шаблоне Джинджей вывел {{ variable }}. Если это происходит если except то по идее должно вывести. Но нет, вывода не происходит. Переменную же вывожу после формы в html-е. Просто добавил {{ variable }}

Comment: Ну сейчас в показанном в вопросе коде нету никакого variable, так что непонятно о чём речь